# Pip timeouts with host reset mesage every time under VirtualBox

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

When trying to install requirements.txt (or anything else for the matter), pip just time-outs every time with host reset message.

This happens only under VirtualBox (guest CentOS 6.4 64-bit, host Windows 7 64-bit), and only for pip/easy_install tools. Almost appears as pypi CDN just flat out rejects the connections.

Anyone knows what can cause this, and how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, apparently our router doesn't like the extra hope the virtual machine adds, works fine in another place.